# How to focus on desktop with keyboard in windows?

Tags: windows, windows-7, keyboard

I mean not to focus on the items on the desktop,I want to focus on the wallpaper

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Press Windows+D. Then your focus is on the desktop.

You can not focus on the wallpaper. It is just a background.

Do you want to focus on the image file in the explorer?

Comment: But windows+D is focus on the desktop's items,not the desktop itself,according to what you mean,I want to focus on the background,not the items' icons.@User

Comment: 1. What you want is not originally supported by Windows. Maybe you will find some application that makes it possible. 2. Why do you want to do this? Is it because you have no mouse and want to produce the right-click on the background?

Comment: Yes,you are clever@User

Comment: Pressing windows + D and then pressing the 'APPS' button (between strg right and altgr on my keyboard) opens the same menu as when you right-click on the desktop. :)

Comment: I don't have those buttons.